# restfull controller ignore update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, haml, restful-architecture

I can't update field in database table. Why, when I working in edit template(controller/id/edit), rails redirect me to CREATE action and create a new row in table? It must redirect me to update action and update only one field.
Controller:

```
  def create
 Question.create(:user_id => session[:user_id], :question => params[:question][:question])
 end

  def update
  debugger #not go there
  @update = Question.find(params[:id])
  @update.update_attributes(params[:question_status])
 end
```

edit template

```
= form_for Question.new do |w|
  %p
= w.label :question_status, :caption => "question status: "
= w.text_field :question_status
  %p
= w.submit "Update"
```

routs.rb

```
match "questions/logout" => "questions#logout"
match "questions/show_all_questions" => "questions#show_all_questions"
match "questions/update" => "questions#update"
resources :questions

get "questions/create" 
get "questions/show"
get "questions/update"
get "questions/destroy"
get "questions/new"
get "questions/edit"
get "questions/index"
```

Comment: 1. Edit form with action `Question.new`? are you sure?. 2. You have use `resources :questions` on `routes.rb`, why you add get "questions/....." on your `routes.rb` I think to use enough `resources :questions`.

Comment: when i trying Question.update or Question.edit have this error
`wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)`
`undefined method `edit'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It redirects you to the create method because your call Question.new.

you should have your form like:

```
= form_for Question do |w|
```

Comment: I have questions: why are you using you using Question? and not the usual @question ?

Comment: but field not update...
in controller I trying this
`@update = Question.find(params[:id])#
  @update.update_attributes(params[:question_status])`

Comment: if status is a field in question. try @update.update_attributes(params[:status]) if status is inside the question you can access it with @update.update_attributes(params[:question][:status])

Comment: because i should use parameters in controller as a hash. Solved!!!
`@update.update_attributes(:question_status => params[:question][:question_status])`
thank you again